# C# MVC implementing MySql.Web.Security.MySqlSimpleMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

On an existing MVC site, it was needed to add Authentication with Local accounts, so I followed this 
[Oracle blog post guide](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/how_to_using_simplemembserhipprovider_with)

When doing it on a new (proof-of-concept) project, all run fine.

But when doing this in my existing site, upon running:

```
if (WebSecurity.Login(a_Username, a_Password))
    Authenticated = true;
else
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
```

In the AccountController, I get:

```
InvalidOperationException in WebMatrix.WebData.dll
```

With Message

```
To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".
At
WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.VerifyProvider() +106
```

Could it be a problem of my WebMatrix.WebData version?
Any ideas please?

**Update**: Let me note that the test site (which is working) was created as a VS2012 MVC4 Web Application and I see that all the References regarding System.Web (i.e. System.Web.Mvc version 4.0.0 ) are of earlier version than in my actual Site (i.e. System.Web.Mvc version 5.2.2). I suppose this should not be a problem, as long as there is backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason for my problem.
It was the version of WebMatrix.Data dependency library.

I tried to update it through Nuget Package Manager and that solved the problem, so, now I do not get these exceptions while calling WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity class methods.

**The Solution:**

- Right click on your website project => Manage Nuget Packages.
- Select "Online" from the left menu to display all available online nuget packages.
- Type WebMatrix in the Search field and scroll until you find "ASP.Net Web Pages 2 Database Library"
- Select it and click "Install"

After this I just built the solution and tested the code, and it run just fine!

PS: In the package information it says "Legacy package, WebMatrix.Data is now included in the 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data' package." Also: "Dependencies        Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data (≥ 2.0.20710)"